# Привильный синтаксис для вызова sort() c++ в классе

Tags: c++, сортировка

Поробовал написать класс для сортировки вектора векторов по определенному полю

```
#pragma once
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>  

using namespace std;

class Sorter
{
private:
    int numField;
public:

    bool comp(const vector<string>& a, const vector<string>& b)
    {
        return a[numField] < b[numField]; 
    }

    void getSort(vector<vector<string>>& catalogue, int field)
    {

        numField = field;
        if (numField > (int)catalogue.size() || numField < 0) cout << "Поле №" << numField << " осутствует" << endl;
        else sort(catalogue.begin(), catalogue.end(), comp);      
    }
//  Sorter(int);
};
```

но получил сообщение об ошибке:

Ошибка  C3867   "Sorter::comp": нестандартный синтаксис; используйте "&", чтобы создать указатель на член   RD_CompAgr  G:_Disk_G_Docs_pc_Programming\C++\RD_CompAgr\RD_CompAgr\Sorter.h    25

Хотя то же, но не в классе скомпилировалось без ошибок

Comment: потому что в классе  это не то же самое, что  не в классе .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Здесь Вы не можете передать предикатом функцию-член, потому что функцию-член нужно вызывать на конкретном объекте, чего не происходит в данном случае.
Если функция статическая, то данный код сможет сработать.
В Вашем случае функция `comp` должна быть статической, и для этого в Вашем случае нужно будет чтобы поле `numField` также было с спецификатором `static`.
Соответственно вызов функции `sort()` будет следующего вида:
`sort(catalogue.begin(), catalogue.end(), &Sorter::comp);`
Но в этом случае `numField` будет идентичным во всех экземплярах класса, что может Вам не подойти.
На Вашем месте я бы сделал так:

```
class Sorter
{
private:
    int numField;
public:

    void getSort(vector<vector<string>>& catalogue, int field)
    {
        const auto comp = [&](const vector<string>& a, const vector<string>& b)
        {
            return a[numField] < b[numField];
        };
        numField = field;
        if (numField > (int)catalogue.size() || numField < 0) cout << "Поле №" << numField << " осутствует" << endl;
        else sort(catalogue.begin(), catalogue.end(), comp);
    }
    //  Sorter(int);
};
```

То есть вместо функции `sort()`, которая определена в классе, создать лямбу внутри функции и использовать ее.

Comment: Для статической функции `&Sorter::comp` не обязательно писать, просто `comp` будет работать.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, да, Вы правы. Просто для наглядности написал.

Comment: Ну и смысл запихивать все это в класс?!..

Comment: @Harry, я не знаю в чем смысл, но вопрос состоял в этом.

Comment: @Lex Marchenko СПАСИБО!!! Особенно за объяснение. Сделал статическими фунцию и переменную - ошибки исчезли. После проверки оттестирую вариант с лямбдой.

Comment: @Harry Смысл: нужно было реализовать агрегацию классов (задание такое :) ). Понимаю, что притянуто за уши, неправильно, но попробовал сделать первое, что пришло в голову. Полезли ошибкию Мог бросить, но решил разобраться

Comment: @AlexDanko, если ответ помог, можете оценить его как правильный:)

Comment: Результат тетстирования.С функцией и переменной обьявленными статическими работает. Но! Оказалось, что переменную нужно определить ВНЕ класса (в .cpp с main() добавить `int Sorter::numField;`). С лямбдой все тоже работает `sort(catalogue.begin(), catalogue.end(), [&field](const vector<string>& a, const vector<string>& b)
   {
    return a[field] < b[field];    
   }`

Comment: @AlexDanko, да, касательно статик переменной забыл уточнить, но определить ее можно и в header файле, по такому же принципу, как в cpp.